# How to group a table in Sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, pivot-table

I have the following table, `Tasks`:

| ID | Task | Type | Time_Taken |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | task1 | type1 | 01h:00m |
| 2 | task1 | type2 | 02h:00m |
| 3 | task2 | type1 | 00h:30m |
| 4 | task2 | type2 | 00h:30m |
| 5 | task3 | type1 | 01h:00m |
| 6 | task3 | type2 | 04h:00m |

I want to create a new table from the `Tasks` table which should be

| Task | type1_time | type2_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| task1 | 01h:00m | 02h:00m |
| task2 | 00h:30m | 00h:30m |
| task3 | 01h:00m | 04h:00m |

Can you help me in building an sql query for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one entry per task and type. As you want to group by task, you can use `MIN` or `MAX` to access the type's value, as there is only one.

```
select
  task,
  min(case when type = 'type1' then time_taken end) as type1time,
  min(case when type = 'type2' then time_taken end) as type2time
from tasks
group by task
order by task;
```

This is called conditional aggregation, because we use an aggregate function on a condition (here: when the row matches the desired type).

Answer (score 1):

I assume this SQL query is processed in MySQL database. Please refer to the query below:

```
select Task, 
sum(if(Type='type1', Time_Taken,0)) as type1_time,
sum(if(Type='type2', Time_Taken,0)) as type2_time from Tasks 
group by Task
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what if the time_taken column was of 'char' type.

Comment: I've modified the question for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Solution INNER JOIN
SELECT type1.Task, type1.Time_Taken as 'type1_time', type2.Time_Taken as 'type2_time'
FROM Task type1 
INNER JOIN Task type2 on type1.Task = type2.Task
WHERE type1.Type = 'type1'
    AND type2.Type = 'type2';

--Solution GROUP_CONCAT
SELECT  
        t.Task,
        GROUP_CONCAT(IF(t.Type = "type1", t.Time_Taken, NULL)) AS 'type1_time',
        GROUP_CONCAT(IF(t.Type = "type2", t.Time_Taken, NULL)) AS 'type2_time'
FROM Task t
GROUP BY t.Task;
```

DEMO : https://paiza.io/projects/e/V9GtkWoJQAqewynjRXZ9-Q?theme=twilight

Answer (score 0):

My query will you give you the result as your are expecting. Demo link: [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tZhJXYcVaj712TCYhqgEB9/0)

```
SELECT Task, 
SEC_TO_TIME(sum(if(Type='type1', TIME_TO_SEC(Time_Taken),0))) as type1_time,
SEC_TO_TIME(sum(if(Type='type2', TIME_TO_SEC(Time_Taken),0))) as type2_time 
FROM Tasks 
GROUP BY Task
```